# undefined local variable or method `env' for method in controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gon

I'm currently using 'gon' to pass my client id for payment to the javascript sdk of the payment gateway (Braintree in my case).

When I try to set the client id generated to a 'gon' variable, I'm facing this error.

Basically this is my code

```
def new
  gon.client_token = generate_client_token
end
.
.
.
private
def generate_client_token
  Braintree::ClientToken.generate
end
```

And I'm using 'figaro' for environment variables.

Comment: provide stack-trace..

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of gon 6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My rails 5.2.3 and gon 5.2.3. After upgrading the gon to 6.2.0 the issue went away.